# simply connected/path connected of a set in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Is the set $\{(x,y)\ |\ x^2-y^2<0\}$ in $\Bbb R^2$path connected? Is it simply connected?

I am having trouble with these concepts in these scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you draw it?

Comment: to draw http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+region++x%5E2-y%5E2+%3C0

Comment: im still confused understanding how to visualize whether it is path connected or simply connected or neither or both

Answer (score 0):

The set in question is somewhat more simply expressed as $\{(x, y)\ :\ |x| < |y|\}$. Note in particular that when $y = 0$, no value of $x$ satisfies the inequality, which is the key to answering the first question.

The second question depends on exactly how simply connected is defined. (Do you demand that simply connected $\implies$ path connected, or just that all loops are homotopic to $0$?) If the latter, consider that the two components of this set are each homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.